# Calculate total based on an IF statement

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Can I get some help creating a formula in MS excel 2013 to do the following:

I have Column A with list of user names, which are repeating. Column B with starting time and Column C with end time.

I need to Count how many times the difference between column B and C is greater then 30 minutes, per user.

Here is an example:

[image: Example]

Comment: Easiest way to me: Add a column to calculate End Time - Start Time in minutes and then use a Pivot Table. You can also do something with a SumProduct formula. It might bear a resemblance to this: `=SUMPRODUCT((A$2:A$10="Bob")*((C$2:C$10-B$2:B$10)>30))` Start with one of those and see how far you get.

Answer (score 1):

In Cell say F2 put the following Array formula and drag it down until you get an error in cell. This will give you unique list of Users first of all.

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$8,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($F$1:F1,$A$2:$A$8),0))
```

Press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER within the address bar to create an Array Formula.

Now you will have unique list of Users starting F2 and below. Note that you need to leave a cell above for this formula to work which in fact is your Header anyways.

Now in G2 put the following Array Formula

```
=SUM(IF($A$2:$A$8=F2,IF($C$2:$C$8-$B$2:$B$8>1/48,1,0)))
```

Press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER within the address bar to create an Array Formula and drag it down. This example uses rows A2 thru A8. Column D is only for reference, not used anywhere in formula.

[image]