# Automatically count number of payments in each payment group in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a spreadsheet that looks something like this:

```
DATE      |PYMT AMT
01/01/2000|$1000
02/01/2000|$1000
....
12/01/2000|$1000
01/01/2001|$2000
02/01/2001|$2000
```

How can I create another table that looks like this:

```
Payment Count |Payment Amount  
03            |$1000
02            |$2000
```

`COUNTIF()` helps me to know the payment amounts in advance, by using this formula, =`COUNTIF(B1:B300,"1000")`.

But what if, I don't know in advance what they will be the amount?

Comment: Not very understanding your problem, could you provide a more clearly table about this problem?

Comment: Do you want a Pivot Table?  Can you please clarify your question.

Comment: There isn't really enough information for people to be able to answer.  Are you looking for formulas that calculate payment amount for number of payments?  Do you already have that and you just want to format your information into a table?  What does your information look like?  What formula are you using?

Comment: I made some changes to clarify my question but they were rejected.  So I'm trying again.  I think some of the moderators are too picky.

Comment: Do you mean that you would like to see the Payment Amount column of your output table to list all unique values from the existing table so that instead of Hard Coding e.g. 1000 in your COUNTIF formula, you shall just refer the cell reference? Also in your formula you are entering "1000" as Text (Because it's enclosed in Double Quotes), it will not match if the $ Values are Numerics.

Comment: If my above assumption is right, then you can refer this answer (first part thereof) https://superuser.com/questions/1186983/calculate-total-based-on-an-if-statement/1187004#1187004 to get the unique list of Payment Amounts in output table and then use your COUNTIF formula referring the respective cells rather than hard coding values.

Answer (score 0):

**I'm sure that you are looking for something like this.**

*I'm assuming that you have data in Range `A2:B6`.*

[image]

**How it works:**

1. Write this Array Formula in cell `A10`, finish with `ctrl+Shift+Enter` & fill down.

   ```
   {=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$6, MATCH(0,COUNTIF($A$9:A9, $B$2:$B$6), 0)),"")}
   ```
2. Enter this Formula in cell `B10` & fill down.

   `=IF(A10="","No Val",(COUNTIF($B$2:$B6,A10)))`

**N.B.**

1. First part of above written formula `=IF(A10="","No Val",` will help you to generate error *if you don't know values or you don't have
   values to count.*
2. Second part `(COUNTIF($B$2:$B6,A10)))` will *count the occurrence of payments made.*

*Adjust cell references in the formula as you need.*